# interval questions in questionnaire

Tags: research, questionnaire

A question in questionnaire asks age of respondents by giving four options as follows:

- below 20
- 20 to 40
- 41 to 60
- above 61

would it be considered ordinal scale question if yes then why? if these options doesn't have equal gap what scale would be used?? (nominal or ordinal)

Comment: What benefit would it be to the user to create an interval with the questions presented?

Comment: Who are the respondents and how will the answers be used?

Answer (score 1):

It would be an ordinal-scale question because of the *ordering*.  Each person's answer would be at a point in your series.  The fact that you chunked groups of ages isn't important as long as they are ordered. (Unless you purposefully left out age 61, you probably would want the last group to be "61 and older", not "above 61")

An ordinal scale is any scale in which values increase from one end to the other.  Usually, in social-science research, the increase is regular but it doesn't have to be:  logarithmic scales (e.g.) are also ordinal.